# improving on collision detection

Tags: c++, collision-detection, game-engine, collision, game-physics

I have two functions that I will be using to check collisions between objects on the screen, as these functions are things that are going to be executed a lot I would like to ensure they run at maximum efficiency, and because they currently seem quite messy I was wondering if I could get your help.

My functions are as follows: 
This is the function that would actually be called on the object:

```
bool ScreenObject::intersects(ScreenObject & a,ScreenObject & b) {
    if(inter(a,b))
        return true;
    else
        return inter(b,a);
}
```

and this is inter:

```
bool inter(ScreenObject & a,ScreenObject & b) {
    if(a->getsx()>b->getsx()) {
        if(a->getsx()<b->getSxmax()) {
            if(a->getsy()>b->getsy())) {
                if(a->getsy<b->getSymax()) {
                    return true;
                }
            } else {
                if(b->getsy()>a->getsy())) {
                    if(b->getsy<a->getSymax()) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

getsx/getsy return the minimum value of x/y(ie the lower left corner of the object) whereas getSxmax/getSymax return the maximum. My question is, is there a way to make this code better, as currently this seems quite poorly executed.

Comment: What are the shape of the objects? For example, if one object is convex and another is concave then just checking minimum or maximum may return false positive resutls.

Comment: in this case the majority of the objects will be rectangular, however there will be others which are not, could you explain how to check against that as well, I was thinking that I would have to check against coordinates which line up with the objects curve, however if there is a better way please explain

Comment: Have a look at this gamedev.se topic: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/586/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-work-out-2d-bounding-box-intersection

Answer (score 1):

You are right.  This is pretty messy.  You want to track the rectangular extent of each object:

```
typedef struct range { int min, max; } RANGE;
typedef struct bb { RANGE x, y; } BOUNDING_BOX;
```

The key operation is to find that there is *no* overlap in one dimension by determining that object A must lie to either side of B. This is disjointness:

```
bool disjoint(RANGE *a, RANGE *b) { return b->max < a->min || b->min > a->max; }
```

Now we can use this twice to find there is no overlap in 2d:

```
bool disjoint(BOUNDING_BOX *a, BOUNDING_BOX *b) {
  return disjoint(&a->x, &b->x) || disjoint(&a->y, &b->y);
}
```

Of course collision is the logical complement of disjoint, at least for rectangular objects.

For other shapes, you can still use rectangular extents to eliminate most of the cost of collision tests.  If the extents are disjoint, you're sure there is no collision.  If the are not disjoint, then you must do the more expensive tests for collision of general polygons.  There is some basic information [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15573/2D-Polygon-Collision-Detection).  But there are several big books on this topic.

For @DanielKO who doesn't like C conventions even though they express the computation more succinctly than OO for this question; also omitting constructor and other boilerplate:

```
class Extent { 
  public:
    bool isDisjointWithRespectTo(Extent &other) {
      return max < other.min || other.min > max; 
    }
  private:
    int min, max;
}

class BoundingBox {
  public:
    bool isDisjointWithRespectTo(BoundingBox &other) {
       return x.isDisjointWithRespectTo(other.x) || y.isDisjointWithRespectTo(other.y);
    }
    bool intersectsWith(BoundingBox &other) { return !isDisjointWithRespectTo(other); }
  private:
    Extent x, y;
}
```

The constructors need to make sure `min` and `max` are correctly ordered in both versions.

Comment: For the love of god, write an axis-aligned bounding box class with a proper intersection test, like everyone else. OOP exists precisely to make simple concepts into simple readable code.

Comment: @DanielKO I'm sorry this caused you such stress that you felt a need to invoke your deity. The OP was asking about how to arrange the tests, so my intent was just to give a code fragment that showed a disjointness test, not to write complete classes.

Comment: About the OOP, the question is tagged C++, so it's appropriate to use the tool if it's available in the language. A bounding box is a fairly intuitive concept (please don't call it `Extent` in your C version then use it again to mean an interval, names matter), it makes sense to represent it explicitly. A `ScreenObject` will have a bounding box, not pairs of intervals (which is a reasonable implementation detail).

Comment: @DanielKO  I'm pretty sure my code would compile as C++ just fine, though I haven't tried it. Ah, but the term extent predates bounding box by quite a few years. I learned it from Brian Barsky in 1984.  It's sad that it's been replace by the less precised Bounding box, due to Adobe, I believe.  Minimum bounding box would be better. Still it's reasonable to make the examples consistent, so I'll do that.

Comment: According to Wikipedia, the word "computer" was first used by Richard Braithwait in 1613: "I referred to a person who carried out calculations, or computations, and the word continued with the same meaning until the middle of the 20th century." Words evolve to express meanings that are relevant. The meaning of "extent" depends heavily on context, while "bounding box" (Who said it had to be minimum? Even a generously padded bounding box is ok, as long as it encloses the related object) is pretty explicit (it's shaped like a box, and it bounds something) and has no ambiguous meanings.